# How can I make Fluent NH QueryOver create SQL leftjoin using on foreignkey?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, foreign-key-relationship, queryover

using FNH QueryOver I need to join to a entity using a foreign key posted to the other entity table.
When I run the QueryOver which uses the following

```
.Left.JoinAlias(() => primaryAlias.minorEntity, () => minorAlias)
```

NHProf captures SQL as follows

```
       left outer join [minorEntity] minorentity6_
     on this_.Id = userlogind6_.Id
```

Actually the FK is not the key of the entity but the foreign key (FKId), so it should read;

```
on this_.Id = userlogind6_.FKId
```

So how can I get fluent NH QueryOver to do this?

Thanks

Comment: What does your mapping look like?

Answer (score 0):

Within your mapping you would have to set the FKId as key column within your Reference/ManyTo... or whatever mapping.

Maybe you just didn't specify that Id relationship correctly. NHibernate will not assume something as long as you specify it.